# How to setup haproxy with docker swarm where haproxy is "outside" the overlay network?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, haproxy, docker-swarm-mode

I'm trying to setup a docker based system with the least amount of network abstraction/virtualization possible. This is why I avoided k8s and am trying docker-swarm instead.

I'd like `haproxy` to be started directly via `systemd` and listen to external traffic on ports 80/443 directly, i.e. without docker coming into the picture. However, when proxying traffing to backend servers, I'd like it to connect to docker-swarm services running in `dnsrr` mode.

How do I set this up? I've read [this blog post](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/haproxy-on-docker-swarm-load-balancing-and-dns-service-discovery/) multiple times, but in all three configurations it seems that `haproxy` itself is running as a docker-swarm service. I do not want any network "abstraction" to come between haproxy and customer-facing traffic.

Is a setup like this possible?

PS: A related question might be, how do I communicate between the host and a docker-swarm container running on the same host?  I tried pinging `10.0.6.75` (the container's IP address) on the same host on which it was running, but it didn't work. Do I need to create some network route, or make some entry in iptables to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

If you use docker, you can't avoid a layer of network abstraction, because it [creates a virtual network](https://docs.docker.com/network/) with it's own routes and should be inaccesible to your host networks by default.

If all you want is to make docker services accessible without the hassle, **I'd recommend you to [use traefik to track docker services](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/providers/docker/) instead of haproxy**. But, if you insist in using HAproxy, you can either:

### [Run haproxy inside a docker container](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/how-to-run-haproxy-with-docker/)

And expose it to the host network.

```
# add this service to your swarm configuration
version: "3.3"
services:
  proxy:
    image: haproxy
    configs:
      - source: haproxy
        target: /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
    ports:
      # Add here all the ports you want managed by haproxy
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
# this is your current haproxy config
configs:
  haproxy:
    file: ./haproxy.conf
```

### Use a [host networking](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/) for your docker services

```
version: "3.3"
# add this network to your swarm configuration
networks:
  host:
    driver: host
services:
  app:
    image: whatever
    ...
    # add this network to your apps
    networks:
      host:
```

### Manually [bind the HAproxy service to the network interface(s)](https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/aloha/latest/administration/network/network-interfaces/)

Inspect the docker network for your services.

```
$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID     NAME                               DRIVER    SCOPE
4d992742292c   bridge                             bridge    local
$ docker network inspect ${ID_OR_NAME}
[
    {
       "Name": "bridge",
       "Id": "4d9927...",
       "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
       },
       ...
       "Options": {
            ...
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
       }
...
```

Add to your haproxy configuration:

```
service network DEVICE # i.e. docker0
  auto off
  ip address 172.17.0.11 # ensure it's available
  ip route 172.17.0.1 172.17.0.1
```

Comment: My understanding of docker networking might be wrong, but I noticed that even when I use host networking with docker-swarm, there is a `docker-proxy` process that is listening to the port in question on the host's network. Is this expected? And if it is, then is there _any_ way whatsoever to get haproxy to listen to on the port on the host's network?

Comment: Does `traefik` does this out-of-the-box, i.e. the external port is controlled directly by traefik and it proxies the traffic to docker's virtual network? Is traefik as stable and scalable as haproxy? I'm not hung-up on haproxy, but I'm concerned about having too many layers of abstraction/virtualization for a front-facing proxy component, which needs to be super-fast.

Comment: I can run a docker container via `--net host` where the port/socket is directly controlled by the underlying process and not `docker-proxy`. How do I achieve this in `docker compose`. That would be a first step, right?